Add another data to ChartJS X-Axis in relation
I am trying to add another data to my chart.
I have to line which a representing a reference data. Now I want to add some points which are showing real results.
The chart should show that the points are in the tolerance range of the reference.
But i don't know how to solve this right now.
The data of the reference and real data are different datasets. But both have same same kind of data.
For example: Both have an error value (y-axis) and both have a flowrate (x-axis).
But how can i add and show the data correctly together?
I hope anyone of you have an idea.
Adjusting label. Have also tried with "ticks".
Open for any idea out there.

That's the chart what I have now. The points near the middle are showing wrong. X-axis have flowrates and last point has also a flowrate of for example "250" but I can't mix the x-axis.


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Hello, World!</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
      <h1 class="title">Hello World!</h1>
      <p id="currentTime"></p>
      
      <!-- Add the canvas element for the chart -->
      <canvas id="errorChart"></canvas>
      
      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
      <script>
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
            const ctx = document.getElementById('errorChart').getContext('2d');

            // Beispiel-Datensatz für labels, der X- und Y-Werte enthält
            let referenceData = [
                { x: 308.75, y: 0.19 }, { x: 292.5, y: 0.22 },
                { x: 276.25, y: 0.21 }, { x: 260, y: 0.19 },
                { x: 243.75, y: 0.17 }, { x: 227.5, y: 0.23 },
                { x: 211.25, y: 0.18 }, { x: 195, y: 0.21 },
                { x: 178.75, y: 0.22 }, { x: 162.5, y: 0.18 },
                { x: 146.25, y: 0.23 }, { x: 130, y: 0.19 },
                { x: 113.75, y: 0.20 }, { x: 97.5, y: 0.26 },
                { x: 81.25, y: 0.32 }, { x: 65, y: 0.39 },
                { x: 48.75, y: 0.49 }, { x: 45.5, y: 0.55 },
                { x: 42.25, y: 0.61 }, { x: 39, y: 0.60 },
                { x: 35.75, y: 0.71 }, { x: 32.5, y: 0.78 },
                { x: 29.25, y: 0.81 }, { x: 26, y: 0.97 },
                { x: 22.75, y: 1.09 }, { x: 19.5, y: 1.22 },
                { x: 16.25, y: 1.47 }, { x: 13, y: 1.85 },
                { x: 9.75, y: 2.48 }, { x: 6.5, y: 3.72 },
                { x: 3.25, y: 7.45 }, { x: 1.625, y: 14.90 },
                { x: 0.975, y: 24.80 }
            ];

            // Sortiere labelsData nach x-Werten in aufsteigender Reihenfolge
            referenceData.sort((a, b) => a.x - b.x);

            // Extrahiere die X-Werte als Labels für die X-Achse
            const labels = referenceData.map(point => point.x.toFixed(2));

            // Beispiel-Datensatz für Fehlerdaten mit X- und Y-Werten
            const fehlerData = [
                { x: 25, y: 0.08 }, { x: 30, y: -0.07 },
                { x: 35, y: 0.03 }, { x: 45, y: 0.04 },
                { x: 50, y: 0.01 }, { x: 150, y: 0.01 },
                { x: 280, y: 0.01 }
            ];

            // Beispielwerte für positive und negative Kurven, basierend auf fehlerData
            const positiveValues = referenceData.map(point => ({
                x: point.x,
                y: (point.y + 0.05).toFixed(2)
            }));

            const negativeValues = referenceData.map(point => ({
                x: point.x,
                y: (point.y - 0.05).toFixed(2)
            }));

            // Berechne den minimalen und maximalen Wert aus den Daten
            const yMin = -1.5;
            const yMax = 1.5;

            // Chart initialisieren
            const errorChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                type: 'line',
                data: {
                    labels: labels, // X-Achsen-Werte (aus labelsData extrahiert)
                    datasets: [
                        {
                            label: 'Fehler Punkte', // Bezeichnung für Fehlerpunkte
                            data: fehlerData, // Fehlerdaten als Punkte (mit X- und Y-Werten)
                            borderColor: 'transparent', // Keine Linienfarbe
                            backgroundColor: '#FE661C', // Hintergrundfarbe der Punkte
                            pointBorderColor: '#FE661C', // Randfarbe der Punkte
                            pointBackgroundColor: '#FE661C', // Hintergrundfarbe der Punkte
                            pointStyle: 'rectRot',
                            pointRadius: 2, // Größe der Punkte
                            pointHoverRadius: 3, // Größe der Punkte beim Hover
                            fill: false // Keine Fläche unter der Linie füllen
                        },
                        {
                            label: 'Kurve von -1,5 bis 0,1',
                            data: negativeValues,
                            borderColor: '#4FAD2F', // Farbe der Kurve
                            borderWidth: 2, // Breite der Kurve
                            tension: 0.8, // Kurvenansicht
                            cubicInterpolationMode: 'monotone',
                            pointRadius: 0, // Punkte ausblenden
                            fill: false // Keine Fläche unter der Kurve füllen
                        },
                        {
                            label: 'Kurve von +1,5 bis 0,1',
                            data: positiveValues, // Datenpunkte
                            borderColor: '#004C97', // Farbe der Kurve
                            borderWidth: 2, // Breite der Kurve
                            tension: 0.8, // Kurvenansicht
                            cubicInterpolationMode: 'monotone',
                            pointRadius: 0, // Punkte ausblenden
                            fill: false // Keine Fläche unter der Kurve füllen
                        }
                    ]
                },
                options: {
                    animation: false, // Animation deaktivieren
                    responsive: true,
                    maintainAspectRatio: false,
                    scales: {
                        x: {
                            title: {
                                display: true,
                                text: 'Durchfluss / Flow Rate [kg/h]',
                                font: {
                                    family: 'Roboto, sans-serif',
                                    weight: 'normal',
                                    size: 14,
                                    color: '#333'
                                }
                            },
                            ticks: {
                                font: {
                                    family: 'Roboto, sans-serif',
                                    weight: 'normal',
                                    size: 12,
                                    color: '#333'
                                },
                                color: '#666'
                            },
                            beginAtZero: true,
                            min: 0,
                            max: 50,
                            stepSize: 5,
                            grid: {
                                display: false,
                                color: '#ddd',
                                borderColor: '#aaa',
                                borderWidth: 1
                            }
                        },
                        y: {
                            title: {
                                display: true,
                                text: 'Fehler/Error [%]',
                                font: {
                                    family: 'Roboto, sans-serif',
                                    weight: 'normal',
                                    color: '#333'
                                }
                            },
                            ticks: {
                                font: {
                                    family: 'Roboto, sans-serif',
                                    weight: 'normal',
                                    color: '#333'
                                },
                                callback: function (value) {
                                    return value.toFixed(1); // Formatierung der Y-Werte
                                },
                                color: '#666'
                            },
                            grid: {
                                display: false,
                                color: '#ddd',
                                borderColor: '#aaa',
                                borderWidth: 1
                            },
                            min: yMin, // Minimale Y-Achsen-Skalierung
                            max: yMax   // Maximale Y-Achsen-Skalierung
                        }
                    },
                    plugins: {
                        legend: {
                            display: false, // Legende anzeigen
                            labels: {
                                color: '#333',
                                font: {
                                    family: 'Roboto, sans-serif',
                                    weight: 'normal'
                                }
                            },
                            title: {
                                display: true,
                                text: 'Genauigkeitskurve / Accuracy - Curve',
                                color: '#333',
                                font: {
                                    family: 'Roboto, sans-serif',
                                    weight: 'normal',
                                    size: 14
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        tooltip: {
                            backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8)',
                            titleColor: '#fff',
                            bodyColor: '#fff',
                            borderColor: '#FF6819',
                            borderWidth: 1,
                            padding: 10
                        }
                    },
                    devicePixelRatio: 4
                }
            });
        });
      </script>
  </body>
</html>




You should remove data.labels and add  tooptions.scales.x,  the propertytype: "linear"; this way all the x properties of your datasets data will be used.

saved my day! Thank you!
